# Why am I receiving MediaWiki email message on my own page edits?

Tags: email, configuration, wiki, mediawiki

Setting up a new wiki server for MediaWiki, I see that I am getting email notification messages for emails (on my watchlist) when *I* edit the page. This should not happen - it should only happen when *someone else* edits the page.

Furthermore, I get an email *each time* they edit the page. This is also incorrect: it should only happen after their first edit and then I should not receive any emails until I view the changed page.

Does anyone know what is happening? I don't see anything about this in the [manual](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Configuration_settings#Email_notification_.28Enotif.29_settings).

**Update:** this directly contradicts the **[documentation](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Email_notification/test_cases#General)**. (Note: this link is documentation for an extension but the text is correct: this is core functionality.)

**Update 2:** the MediaWiki version is 1.15.4. <s>And it seems only to be happening to **administrators**</s>.

**Solved:** my mistake; I was using [CategoryWatch](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CategoryWatch). Blush.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake: I was using [CategoryWatch](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CategoryWatch). *Blush*.

Answer (score 0):

Are you making these edits anonymously (ie - you are not logged in)?

Comment: good question but, no, all users are logged into automatically via LDAP so there are no anonymous edits. It seems to be only happening to administrators...